# Reflective Glass shader, like those in our window

Tags: materials, transparency, glass, reflection

I want my glass in Blender to be reflective and also transparent, like most glasses of the windows (not MS Windows).

They reflect light to the lighter side. For example, during the day, it behaves like mirror in the outside and the inside of the building isn't seen from the outside. But during the night, the inside is ligher, so it behaves like mirror in the inside, and we can see inside the building while looking from the outside.

How to achieve this effect in Blender? (The day/night example was just for explaining it, so please suggest shaders and materials, not different materials for each time! I want a single material and a single window glass)

Thanks

Comment: A lot of the mirror effect depends on the lighting and what side of the glass is brighter. A plane with a **glass shader** will look like a mirror if behind it there is a black or very dark background. Likewise, if the reflected environment is darker than what you see through the glass, then the reflections will not be as noticeable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The standard *Glass shader* gives you exactly that.
Or if you prefer *Principled BSDF* like me:

- Set *Transmission* to 1
- Use *Roughness* and *Transmission roughness* to control the glass type
- Add thickness to your glass for realistic results

*Suzanne on one side, and a black material on the other to make a mirror*

[image]

To make this work in Eevee

- enable *Refraction* in the Render tab
- enable *Screen Space Refraction* in your material settings

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: I'll check that

Comment: Would you mind if you share a blend file? I'm not able to reproduce it. Eevee?

Comment: Hi :). I added a solution for Eevee. Just tick two boxes and it will work :).

Comment: ok, thanks @JachymMichal